# Angular budgets with Material colors

Tags: angular, material-design

According to the [configuration guide](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-size-budgets) from Angular about the bugdet sizes I have a budget for styles of 2kb. As soon as I include Material color themes I exceed the size to about 14kb total - i.e. 12kb more than expected.

According the to [style guide](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette) of Material different palettes should work in harmony with each other.

```
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

$app-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$app-teal: mat.define-palette(mat.$teal-palette);

$app-theme: mat.define-light-theme($app-primary, $app-teal);
// Create a config with the default typography levels.
$config: mat.define-typography-config();
@mixin mix-app-theme($app-theme) {

  .mat-button-toggle-checked {
    background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($app-teal, 400);
    // background-color: var(--mat-color-teal-400);
    color: mat.get-color-from-palette($app-teal, default-contrast);
  }
}

// Include the mixin
@include mix-app-theme($app-theme);
```

Is there a way to follow the configuration guide and still have access to use the different palettes?

Answer (score 1):

Aren't the budget guides only for component styles? I do not receive these warnings when defining my material theme at `...src/app/styles/_material_theme.scss`. In fact my styles folder contains multiple scss files that exceed the 2kb limit and do not trigger the warning (for clarity these are all `@imports` into my `global.scss` file). Consider where you are defining your theme file.

Additionally, if you need to you can extend the warning/error limits by adjusting the values in your config:

```js
// angular.json

{
    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
    "maximumWarning": "2kb",
    "maximumError": "50kb"
}
```